# Unable to load the data from a MS SQL database from Microsoft Azure Databricks notebook

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I want to retrieve the data from a MS SQL database (not hosted on Azure) to Microsoft Azure Databricks notebook.
Here are the steps of what I have done:

1. go on the portal of azure and create a resource groups
2. create Azure Databricks Service (but I do NOT use the 'Deploy Azure Databricks workspace in your own Virtual Network (VNet)' option → maybe I should...)
3. once Azure Databricks Service is ready, I launch it and create a cluster without specific configuration
4. then I create a notebook (running on the previous cluster) with this script

```py
msSqlServer = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433;ApplicationIntent=readonly;databaseName=" + msSqlDatabase
query = """(select * from mytable)foo"""

df = (
  spark.read.format("jdbc")
  .option("url", msSqlServer)
  .option("dbtable", query)
  .option("user", msSqlUser)
  .option("password", msSqlPassword)
  .load()
)
```

and I get this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port 1433 has failed. Error: &#34;connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.&#34;.
```

Before asking on StackoverFlow, I have contacted my company network and DBA teams. The DBA said the connection is okay but then disconnects immediatly"

For your information, I have followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/sql-databases

Maybe there is something to configure, but I am not in networking at all (I am just a little data scientist who wants to play with notebook on azure databricks and access his company databases). For example how can I `Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall` ?

If you have some idea or you have already met this issue, feel free to share. :)

If you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: Can you post what step you got up to ? Or drop the code you are using into the response. remove your specific credentials

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added some information, I hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already configured your Azure SQL database to listen on TCP/IP traffic on port 1433 then it could be any of following three reasons:

- JDBC connection string in correct.
- Firewall is blocking the incoming connection.
- Azure SQL database is not running.

From Azure Portal get the Azure SQL Database JDBC connection string.

[image]

> SQL Databases using JDBC using Python:

```
jdbcHostname = "chepra.database.windows.net"
jdbcDatabase = "chepra"
jdbcPort = "1433"
username = "chepra"
password = "XXXXXXXXXX"
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : username,
  "password" : password,
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
pushdown_query = "(Select * from customers where CustomerID = 2) CustomerID"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

[image]

> SQL Databases using JDBC using Scala:

```
val jdbcHostname = "chepra.database.windows.net"
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = "chepra"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

// Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()

connectionProperties.put("user", s"chepra")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"XXXXXXXXXX")

val employees_table = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "customers", connectionProperties)
employees_table.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I was sick, I will try what you have recommended. Thank you by the way :)

Comment: But as I said the database is not hosted on Auzre :/

Comment: were you able to solve it?